# Example of $M$ not f.g. such that $\sqrt{\mathrm{Ann}(M)+I}\subseteq \sqrt{\mathrm{Ann}(M/IM)}$ is proper

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

This is related to Exercise 2.2 from Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory*.

Let $M$ be an f.g. module over a ring $A$ and $I\subset A$ be an ideal. Then $\sqrt{\mathrm{Ann}(M/IM)}=\sqrt{\mathrm{Ann}(M)+I}$.

One side inclusion holds all the time by observing $\mathrm{Ann}(M)+I\subseteq \mathrm{Ann}(M/IM)$ and taking radical on both sides $\sqrt{\mathrm{Ann}(M)+I}\subseteq\sqrt{\mathrm{Ann}(M/IM)}$ holds irregardless of $M$ not f.g.

Q1. What is the example when $M$ is not f.g. such that the inclusion is proper? I tried $R[x]$ as $R$-module where $R$ not a domain. So $\mathrm{Ann}(R)+(x^2)\subseteq \mathrm{Ann}(R[x]/(x^2))$. I am not convinced that the inclusion is proper after taking the radical.

Q2. Any good reference on looking for counter examples in algebra? I felt I am incompetent in terms of looking for counterexample most of the time.

Comment: For Q1, take $A$ to be a dvr, $I=\pi A$, the maximal ideal and $M$, the fraction field of $A$, not finitely generated. Then $M/IM=0$, so the annihilator is $A$. But, annihilator of $M$ is zero, so you have proper inclusion.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks a lot. Is this example coming to you naturally?